# differential operators evaluation

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I encountered an expression as follows:

\begin{equation}
k = -\frac{1}{|\nabla \varphi|} \left( \nabla^2\varphi - \frac{(\nabla\varphi\nabla)|\nabla \varphi|}{|\nabla \varphi|} \right)
\end{equation}

where $\varphi$ is a scalar quantity that depends upon position ($x,y,z$).

if I understand correctly, $|\nabla\varphi| = |\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial z}|$ and is a scalar quantity. If it is not scalar then how can operation $\frac{1}{|\nabla \varphi|}$ can be defined?

so how can $\nabla\varphi\nabla$ (second term in the right hand expression) operator can be used on a scalar quantity?

EDIT:
So now that I understand the meaning of the operation, I simplified expression as follows:
\begin{eqnarray}
{(\nabla\varphi\nabla)|\nabla \varphi|} &=& \nabla\varphi \cdot (\nabla |\nabla \varphi| ) \\
&=& \nabla\varphi \cdot \left(\nabla \sqrt{\frac{\partial^2 \varphi}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 \varphi}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2 \varphi}{\partial z^2}}\right) \\
&=&  \nabla\varphi \cdot \left( \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\partial^2\varphi_{x}+\partial^2\varphi_{y}+\partial^2\varphi_{z}}} \right) \left( \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \nabla^2 \varphi i + \frac{\partial }{\partial y} \nabla^2 \varphi j + \frac{\partial }{\partial z} \nabla^2 \varphi k\right) \\
&=& \left( \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\partial^2\varphi_{x}+\partial^2\varphi_{y}+\partial^2\varphi_{z}}} \right)\left(\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x} \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \nabla^2 \varphi  + \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y}\frac{\partial }{\partial y} \nabla^2 \varphi  + \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial z} \frac{\partial }{\partial z} \nabla^2 \varphi \right)
\end{eqnarray}

Is this the correct expression? thanks for your time.

Comment: $\nabla{\phi}$ is a vector, the gradient.  If you are defining $|\nabla{\phi}|$ as the length of the gradient vector then it is the square root of the sum of partial derivatives squared and is indeed a scalar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually if $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ then $$|(x,y,z)|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\tag{1}$$

If $\varphi:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is a funcion defined on a open set of $\mathbb{R}^3$, then $\nabla \varphi$ (if it exists) is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $$\nabla\varphi=\left(\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x},\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial y},\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial z}\right)\tag{2}$$

We get from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that $|\nabla\varphi|:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function, so it does make sense to calculate (if it exists) $\nabla (|\nabla\varphi|)$.

To conclude $\nabla\varphi\nabla (|\nabla\varphi|)=\nabla\varphi\cdot\nabla (|\nabla\varphi|)$ is just the inner product of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: thanks for the answer Tomas. Can you please see if I have simplified expression correctly.